# video freeze after swiped out notifications on ios 11 safari

Tags: ios, safari, webrtc

What I did:

- open a webrtc video call web page such as https://safari.opentokrtc.com/
- setup a video call
- swipe out the notification center, then swipe it back
- the remote video freezed

The remote video is okay, since other device can still watch that video.
I also tried monitorEvents on the video tag and document, got nothing when reproducing this.

Is it possibly a bug of safari?
Or how can I detect the notification center was swiped back?
Thanks.

Comment: Wrong place for this type of question, as it's not programming-related. Maybe ask on SuperUser?

Comment: What ios device/version are you using? What browser/platform is the other endpoint? Also test if you get it on https://appr.tc

Comment: I was using ios 11.0, on the other end, it is Chrome 61 on Mac 10.12,
As last time I tried to run against appr.tc, video tags are all black, due to lack of playsinline attr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reproducible on iPhone 6 and iPad mini 2 with ios 11.0; also reproducible with v3.icelink.fm.

I also confirmed that `window.onblur`/`window.onfocus` events aren't fired when the focus moves out to the notification center, even though it stops the video.

I would recommend filing a bug with Apple/Webkit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @zzxx53

Comment: Appears to be fixed on the latest ios safari 11.2.5